# 'west espressif update' returns a usage error

Tags: esp32, zephyr-rtos, espressif-idf

I am trying to set up zephyr on my esp32 by following this [tutorial](https://www.zephyrproject.org/zephyr-rtos-on-esp32/).

Unfortunaly, when I try `west espressif update` as it is written, I get the following error:

```
usage: west espressif [-h] [-b BAUD] [-p PORT] [-e ELF] [-n EOL] {monitor}
west espressif: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'update' (choose from 'monitor')
```

All the required dependencies have been installed and my cmake version is 3.26.4.

I really don't know what I did wrong. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The commands `west espressif update` and `west espressif install` seem to be outdated.
Have a look at:
https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/issues/54890#issuecomment-1479431830
I can recommend the getting started guide from Zephyr:
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/develop/getting_started/index.html (Make sure you got the latest version)